# Http authentication leads to a 404 page on Expression Engine site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, cpanel, expressionengine

I am trying to password protect an analytics page in the cgi-bin directory using c-panel. In c-panel I’m able to set this up but when I go to analytics page, I’m getting a 404 page instead of an http authentication prompt.

It’s possible it might have to to with the url rewriting in the htaccess to remove 'index.php' from urls for Expression Engine, but I’m not entirely sure.

Any clues are much appreciated!

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) ~gms/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ~gms/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gms\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gms\.com$
RewriteRule ^stats\/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.gms\.com\/cgi\-bin\/awstats\.pl\?config\=gms\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What URL/directory did you set up as password protected? And which URL exactly gives you 404? Are there any other messages in apache's error.log?

Comment: /cgi-bin is the protected directory.  http://www.gms.com/stats which redirects to http://www.gms.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?config=gms.com is the url that gives a 404 (which looks like a site map). If the error log in cpanel is the same as apache's error.log, then there are no related errors from that action.

Comment: So you get 404 after the redirect (on the long url)? And awstats is working with cgi-bin unprotected?